# What to pass in Android Dialog fragment show() method's TAG parameter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, onrestoreinstancestate

Hope you are doing well.

I created a dialog fragment and called show() on the instance. I passed a custom tag to show()'s parameter. The fragment requires no other arguments.
On config change, resizing the window of the app, the app crashes.

```
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35 in com.signal.android.stage:layout/activity_main2: Binary XML file line #35 in com.signal.android.stage:layout/activity_main2: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #35 in com.signal.android.stage:layout/activity_main2: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: DialogFragment 0 doesn't exist in the FragmentManager
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.DialogFragmentNavigator.onRestoreState(DialogFragmentNavigator.java:148)
```

This is a method from the DialogFragmentNavigator.java:

```
    @Override
    public void onRestoreState(@Nullable Bundle savedState) {
        if (savedState != null) {
            mDialogCount = savedState.getInt(KEY_DIALOG_COUNT, 0);
            for (int index = 0; index < mDialogCount; index++) {
                DialogFragment fragment = (DialogFragment) mFragmentManager
                        .findFragmentByTag(DIALOG_TAG + index);
                if (fragment != null) {
                    fragment.getLifecycle().addObserver(mObserver);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("DialogFragment " + index
                            + " doesn't exist in the FragmentManager");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Please see that the DIALOG_TAG that has been used has been hard coded to "androidx-nav-fragment:navigator:dialog:". So It makes sense that the Fragment is not found since I gave a custom TAG.

What is the expectation form the clients calling the show() method?
What tag should be passed to gracefully restore the fragment?

Stay safe!

Comment: should we always just use fragment.getTag() here instead?

Comment: Any solution to this Aleon?

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Comment: Perhaps before showing the dialog you remove the calling fragment from navigation?

Answer (score 0):

The change I have made to the `mTag` field of my custom `DialogFragment` class triggered this same crash when I try to restore the app from background.

As you can see from the source code you have posted, the `tag` field is set and use by `DialogFragmentNavigator` when restoring state. It simply means that you can't use a custom tag.

```kotlin
public final class DialogFragmentNavigator extends Navigator<DialogFragmentNavigator.Destination> {
    ...
    private static final String DIALOG_TAG = "androidx-nav-fragment:navigator:dialog:";
```

So you should either hard-code the prefix: `show(... "androidx-nav-fragment:navigator:dialog:0")`

or show it with the lib: `navigate(R.id.you_dialog_fragment_defined_in_nav_graph_xml)`

or may even `dismiss` it as a workaround to avoid the restoring process:

```kotlin
  override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    dismiss()
  }
```